# Qt: Get MouseMove events from Qsplitter

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to detect when the mouse moves inside a splitter layout. I manage to get the mouse position through an overloading of mouseMoveEvent function in the parent widget but it doesn't work when the mouse is over a 'handle' of the splitter (the place where you can change its dimensions).

I tried also using eventFilters but it seems to work like the previous approach...

Does someone have a similar behaviour? What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.-

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'm creating a project with a Timeline section. each Timeline 'track' contains a QSplitter with 3 areas: Free-Media-Free. I also have a rule in the top were I want to show the mouse position when it is in the Timeline zone.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get mouse movements without pressing mouse keys, you need to enable mouse tracking for the parent widgets and all child widgets. For example, I've created a widget with 2 labels layed out in a splitter. In the constructor I need to do the following:

```
setMouseTracking(true);
ui->label->setMouseTracking(true);
ui->label_2->setMouseTracking(true);
ui->splitter->setMouseTracking(true);
```

And now the parent widget's `mouseMoveEvent` receives all mouse movements.

Comment: Thanks Riateche! Appearantly, all of my child widgets have mousetracking enabled (at least from the Designer panel) and I receive all mouse movements except for the handles of the splitter... If this is working for you, I will re check everything in my project and use your approach... Thanks again!